# Can't see java code when runnig GWT 2.5 in SuperDev mode

Tags: gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I have a GWT 2.5 app following [Thomas Broyer's maven archetypes](https://github.com/tbroyer). I've followed the guidelines explained in the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356714/getting-started-with-the-superdevmode/13278009#13278009) and everything seems to be OK.

The code server is running properly. I browse my app and I start the dev mode from bookmarks copied to the toolbar. After starting dev mode, I can see the dialog with the compile button. After clicking the button, I can see the compiler working in Eclipse console. However, when I try to see java code on Chrome browser I can see javascript code only.

I don't know if it could be relevant, but I'm starting the code server from maven with gwt-maven-plugin's [gwt:run-codeserver](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/run-codeserver-mojo.html) goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7725): Chrome changed the way it deals with Source Maps and this lead to an incompatibility with how GWT produces them.

This is fixed in 2.5.1-rc1 that's just been published to Central (a couple days ago, not yet officially announced). See http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/using-different-gwt-sdk-version.html to use it into your build. I'll release a new version of the gwt-maven-plugin that "links" to this version, and then update the archetypes.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you very much for your help and support to the GWT community.