# Can't get GWT Super Dev Mode to work

Tags: gwt

I've been having trouble lately with getting GWT dev mode to work. First I haven't been able to get IntelliJ 13 to work with dev mode on Mac, though it does work on Windows.

However, with the Firefox 27 release, the dev mode plugin no longer works. Apparently, this is going to be a [permanent problem](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8553). And Chrome is soon to follow as Google will no longer be allowing access for those types of plugins.

So, the solution is supposed to be to use Super Dev Mode. However, as I said, I can't get this to work at all. I've tried through the IntelliJ IDE, but it looks like they've removed the Super Dev Mode checkbox when creating a new debug configuration.

So, I tried on the command line. Looks something like this:

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer -port 6667 -workDir ~/gwt-work -src ~/src/myProject/src/main/java org.foo.myProject.web.MyProject
```

But, all I get is a stack with this:

```
[ERROR] Unable to find 'com/google/gwt/user/User.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

Classpath has all the jars from my project WEB-INF/lib directory as well as all the gwt SDK jars. I'm kind of at a loss right now.

**TL;DR How the hell do you get Super Dev Mode to work?**

Comment: The current version of Intellij 13 does not support SuperDevMode if you are using GWT 2.6.0. The SuperDevMode checkbox is not showed. Switch to the current EAP version, where this bug has been already fixed. To configure SuperDevMode in Intellij, takte a look here: http://www.apptio.com/blog/running-gwt-super-dev-mode-intellij

Answer (score 0):

Here is great answer related to super dev mode.  Check this out

[Getting started with the SuperDevMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356714/getting-started-with-the-superdevmode)

This should solve your problem

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330001/super-dev-mode-in-gwt/18333050?sgp=2#18333050