# GWT SuperDev - Can't find GWT Modules

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I have followed the steps given on this page - [getting-started-with-the-superdevmode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356714/getting-started-with-the-superdevmode)

but I am still getting message - Can't find any GWT Modules on this page. I did some more googling but could not find any solution until now.

I am using GWT 2.6.1 and eclipse kepler 64 bit on ubuntu.

Here are the steps I did.

1. Created a new Web app project for GAE, using GWT 2.6.1 and GAE sdk 1.9.6.
2. Go to Run configurations. Create a new configuration for a "Java Application". Change the main class, Argument and add jar file as shown in the screenshot.
3. Check the apps .gwt.xml file. It already has `<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>`. I have tried adding `devModeRedirectEnabled` property also. It did not help.
4. GWT compile the project.
5. Run the application as Web application. Default jetty config serves the application at 
   `http://localhost:8888/SuperDev.html`. 
   I opened up this page in firefox. I can see the page content.
6. Launch the Java application configuration. It does compile again and gives a success message and tells me to launch 
   `http://localhost:9876/`
7. I opened it in firefox and it shows -[image]
8. Dragged Dev Mode On to firefox's bookmark. And clicked.
9. I get the message - Can't find any GWT Modules on this page.

Following are the configurations for my superdev mode java app. Did I miss anything?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333050/116472; it would help if you could tell exactly what you do. Linking to another post/answer is not enough, as you could have misunderstood/misapplied some steps.

Comment: I have followed the link which I posted in my question, and then followed the link you provided also. Still the same result. I have spent almost an entire day trying to get this straight still no success. I am attaching some screenshots in my question. Please see if anything is missing there. Other than that I have followed your guide word-by-word

Comment: Note: the `gwt.codeserver.port` is to be passed to your web server (Tomcat or whatever), not the CodeServer; though that's not the problem here. That however means there probably is some misunderstanding of the step-by-step guides (either it's not clear enough, or you misunderstood it); so telling us exactly what you did (yes, step by step, paraphrasing the guide if needed) would probably help understand what you did wrong or missed.

Comment: Which browser do you use for your tests?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer - I have added the steps which I did to launch superdev mode.

Comment: @El - I have used both firefox and chrome to test it out. Same results. I do not think this is related to browser. This is purely a configuration issue.

Comment: @Raj: see, you didn't follow my guide word-by-word ;-) It says “Open your app in your browser, then hit the Dev Mode On bookmarklet.” and judging by your updated Q, you clicked the bookmarklet while still on `http://localhost:9876`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to click the bookmarklet **when viewing your compiled web app**.

The last steps should therefore be:

- Dragged Dev Mode On to firefox's bookmark.
- Switched back to my application at `http://localhost:8888/SuperDev.html` and clicked the bookmark

Once you have the bookmarklets, you actually don't really need to open `http://localhost:9876` anymore (you'll find compile logs there, and can browser your code, including the code generated by GWT generators; so it can still be useful).

Comment: Worked perfectly!! You are a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do it with Eclipse Oxygen, Java7 (for run application, for oxygen you have to have java 8), and GWT Eclipse Plugin 3.0.0.

In such an environment all you need to do is:

On project right click > Debug As > GWT Legacy Development Mode with Jetty.

PS:

1. you have to have address like this
   http://127.0.0.1:8888/StockWatcher.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
   NOT like :http://127.0.0.1:8888/StockWatcher.html
2. After openning addres you must additionally install the plugin in the browser - you will be asked for it
3. It work on IE11

Comment: Legacy devmode is not SuperDevMode then, so that doesn't answer the question; and legacy devmode is deprecated (if only because it only works in Internet Explorer)

Comment: Run as `GWT Development Mode with Jetty` is SuperDevMode now.