# Deploying libgdx to html

Tags: libgdx

I tried deploying Libgdx to html using gradle. I copied the content

`html/build/dist`

and all I see in the browser is the badlogic image with a red background (what you would see if you just created a project) Why is that?

Using the superdev I can open it in the browser, i see where it says drag this button but can't play it. there's nothing

```
The code server is ready at http://127.0.0.1:9876/
GET /clean/html
   Cleaning disk caches.
      Cleaned in 29ms.
GET /superdev.html
   [WARN] ignored get request: /superdev.html
   [WARN] not handled: /superdev.html
> Building 91% > :html:superDev^C%
```

[image]

turning the dev mod on I see `Can't find any GWT Modules on this page.`

If I build it normally, I see some warnings about depreciated methods, it builds successfully.

[image]

Assets aren't being loaded by html

Comment: I assume you built the html project before copying the contents?

Comment: @Charanor yes I built then copied the contents of that folder into apache root folder. iI that wrong?

Comment: Is it works in superDev mode ? If yes then once clean your project then run command `./gradlew html:dist`

Comment: @AbhishekAryan what's super dev mode?  How to check that?

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline#running-the-html-project

Comment: @AbhishekAryan sorry for the late reply, please read my edit

Comment: try to run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan please read my edit

Answer (score 5):

I've few links that may be help you :

How to start
[Super Dev mode in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330001/super-dev-mode-in-gwt/18333050#18333050)

Also check this thread 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24265470/3445320

**EDIT**

I've tested on Android Studio with MacOS

Steps :

Run `./gradlew html:clean` to clean your html module

- On Android Studio Terminal I run `./gradlew html:superDev` command
- I got `The code server is ready at http://127.0.0.1:9876/` on terminal
- Then I open Google Chrome, View -> Always Show Bookmarks Bar
- I typed `http://127.0.0.1:9876/` in adress field -> enter
- I got a page having `Dev Mode On` and  `Dev Mode Off`, two buttons
- Drag `Dev Mode On` to bookmarks bar, that is below my Address bar
- Done! now I search http://localhost:8080/html/ , I got my game in browser
- Press `Dev Mode On` button that is in bookmarks bar, I got option for compile

Now I need to deploy my html project

I run `./gradlew html:dist` in Android Studio Terminal

I got `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` in Terminal then I find `dist` folder inside my html module.

> **dist** folder is inside `html module -> build -> dist`

I copied `dist` folder and deployed to my server.

**EDIT 2**

Make sure `badlogic.jpg` is in your assets folder of android module

Check entry in `assets.txt` file and find `badlogic.jpg` inside html `module->war->assets` folder. If file or entry not exist.

Somehow program not able to write in assets folder

- Check what programs have the file/s open
- Check permissions and administrative rights
- Delete the cache files, run "gradlew html:clean html:superDev" for every new run of superDev.
- Check any anti-virus software, they can flag some of GWT's behaviour as suspicious

Comment: the first link for eclipse, im using android studio

Comment: try to run blank Libgdx project, that ensure you've some configuration problem or gwt API problem because All java Api not supported on GWT.

Comment: run `./gradlew html:superDev` on Android Studio Terminal

Comment: when I compile, I still get badlogic.png file not found, the last picture in my question

Comment: have you cleaned your project ?

Comment: There is `assets.txt` file inside `html module->war->assets` folder that having entry of all of your resources that is in inside `android module assets` folder.

Comment: what should I do to it? delete it? or go through all my assets and put them in that file? lengthy process

Comment: i restored the badlogic image, im on linux so no anti virus, I ran using sudo just to make sure I have all rights, now what i see is badlogic image with a red background so not the real game, what i see is like what u see when u first run libgdx..... cant find badlogic.jpg in assets.txt